# How can we prove this using proof by induction?

Tags: theory, context-free-grammar, automata

Let G be the following grammar:

S → T⊣

T → TaTb | TbTa | ε

Show that L(G) = {w⊣| w contains equal numbers of a’s and b’s} using proof by induction on the length of w.

What can be assumed in this situation?

Comment: What is the ⊣ symbol meant to denote? Is it part of the alphabet?

Comment: This belongs in the computer science se. SO is more geared toward programming questions.

Comment: I am not sure of that myself as it is also mentioned under  " L(G) = {w⊣| w contains"

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity we can ignore S symbol and just prove that T produces equal number of a's and b's.

Assuming L={w| w contains equal numbers of a’s and b’s}, the proof is comprised of two parts:
1-Every string with length n that T produces, is in L.
2-Every string in L with length n can be produced by T.

1)
The proof of 1 is simple by induction. The rule (T → ε) produces equal No. of a's and b's, and by induction the rules T → TaTb | TbTa  also keeps a's and b's equal.

2)
We assert that every string in L with length n which ends with b, can be produced by first using the rule T → TaTb.
The proof can be established by numbering the letters. we give each 'a' +1 and each 'b' -1. Every string in L has total rank of '0' (due to equal No of a's and b's). Every string in L ending with b, starts with rank 0 and reaches rank +1 just before last b. It may reaches rank 0 again in between before seeing an 'a'. This is where we can rewrite the string w as T1aT2b in which T1 and T2 are in L too and by induction can be produced by T.(If the rank of w never reaches 0 in between it means that w starts with a, so T1=ε)
The proof for strings ending with 'a' is similar.